# Ser2net returns double lines in terminal. What to do?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, telnet

I'm pretty new to Linux, but I decided to build my own console server to connect to my Cisco devices.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 on which I did install `ser2net` and it works just fine.

But when I enter one of my devices using telnet I get two lines in the terminal it looks just like this:

```
Sw1>
Sw1>
```

if I hit Enter I get this!

```
Sw1>
Sw1>
```

I've tried a lot of things and been searching the internet for a lot of solutions and been fighting with it for 2 days now. I'm tired and lost and in need of some good advice.

What I have done already:

Tried with both Putty and Teraterm including adjusting the terminal settings.

Both CF, LF and Force echo and much more.

I even tried to replace the USB to Serial adapter, which makes me believe that it must be something at the Pi, Linux or `ser2net`. But I can't figure it out.

For any one who is the key to success, here is my `ser2net` configuration:

```
define: &banner \r\nser2net port \p device \d [\B] (Debian GNU/Linux)\r\n\r\n

admin:
    accepter: tcp,8000

connection: &1
    accepter: tcp,8001
    enable: on
    options:
     max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUDK-if00-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &2
    accepter: tcp,8002
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUDK-if01-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &3
    accepter: tcp,8003
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUDK-if02-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &4
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-idh/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUDK-if03-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &5
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUTQ-if00-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &6
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUTQ-if01-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &7
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUTQ-if02-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &8
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78IUTQ-if03-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &9
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78J9GN-if00-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &10
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78J9GN-if01-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &11
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78J9GN-if02-port0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &12
    accepter: tcp,8004
    enable: on
    options:
      max-connections: 4
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT4232H_Device_FT78J9GN-if03-port0,
              9600n81,local
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue, and the following accepter configuration resolved it:

```
accepter: telnet(rfc2217),tcp,8001
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
This Solved my issue.  :-)